# ASP.Net MVC - Insert and Update

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to insert and update into my database but I don't know how to use SQL in this context. Was following iamtimcorey on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIiEv__QNxw&t=2322s

Business Logic (EmloyeeProcessor)

```
public static int CreateEmployee(string Employee_number, string First_name, string Last_name, 
                                 string Email, string Research_Area, string Position_held,
                                 string Highest_qualification, string Department_name)
{
    Employee_Model data = new Employee_Model
        {
            Employee_number = Employee_number,
            First_name = First_name,
            Last_name= Last_name,
            Email = Email,
            Research_area = Research_Area,
            Position_held = Position_held,
            Highest_qualification = Highest_qualification,
            Department_name = Department_name,
        };

    string sql = @"DECLARE @var_Department_id int;
                   SELECT @var_Department_id = Department_id 
                   FROM dbo.Departments 
                   WHERE dbo.Departments.Department_name = @Department_name;
                   INSERT INTO dbo.Employee (Employee_number, First_name, Last_name, Email, Research_area, Position_held, Highest_qualification, @var_Department_id)
                   VALUES (@Employee_number, @First_name, @Last_name, @Email, @Research_area, @Position_held, @Highest_qualification, @Department_name);";

    return SqlDataAccess.SaveData(sql, data);
}
```

`Department_name = Department_name` returns a string that's already present in the Department's Table. Department name is a string in table Departments. I want to pass in the matching Department_id from that table into the New Employee I'm creating.

[image: Foreign Key Relationship - Department_id]

```cs
public static class SqlDataAccess
{
    public static string GetConnectionString(string connectionName = "DemoDB")
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString;
    }

    public static List<T> LoadData<T>(string sql)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            return cnn.Query<T>(sql).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using SqlDataAccess component? Did you try it before? Are you sure that you configured it correctly?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm hearing about it for the first time. From reading about them now - do you need to write any SQL or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Could you show pls SqlDataAccess.SaveData then?

Answer (score 0):

I think the SQL-query should look like this:

```sql
DECLARE @var_Department_id int;

SELECT @var_Department_id = Department_id 
FROM dbo.Departments 
WHERE dbo.Departments.Department_name = @Department_name;

/*
Final insert into table dbo.Employee. 
*/
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee (
    Employee_number, 
    First_name, 
    Last_name, 
    Email, 
    Research_area, 
    Position_held, 
    Highest_qualification, 
    Department_id --This was @var_Department_id in your query
)
VALUES (
    @Employee_number, 
    @First_name, 
    @Last_name, 
    @Email, 
    @Research_area, 
    @Position_held, 
    @Highest_qualification, 
    @var_Department_id --This was @Department_name in your query
);";
```

Comment: Hmm. I run but returns a Null. Is there a better way to do this problem SQL wise?